FMA alignment on A220
I have been doing some research on the A220, and one thing that has confused me is the alignment of the flight mode annunciator on the PFD. Take a look at the autothrottle mode on the far left of the FMA.

It looks like the engaged mode it right-aligned and the armed mode is center-aligned. However, this alignment changes apparently unpredictably when it goes to another mode, such as this:
Asimilar thing happens with the lateral modes, and the vertical mode looks all left-aligned, but with varying margins from the border of that section. Is there a reason why this works that way, or am I missing something basic?

Where are these screenshots coming from?  Are they from the actual aircraft in flight? A full motion simulator? A PC simulator? CBT lessons for the aircraft? Syllabus documents? Other sources?

All of these screenshots are from actual in-flight aircraft.

The A220 (nee Bombardier C Series) uses Rockwell Collins Proline Fusion. The character alignment will be detemined by the software code for the display (or maybe from the data  source). I suggest you send an email on your company's email platform and letterhead to RC tech support.
avionicssupport@collins.com

Well I am a hobbyist, not by any means in professional aviation, so this probably won't get me far. Thanks though.

@IsraelO.Emmanuel Ok I thought you were an A220 driver.  Hey, try it anyway. Can't hurt.
